# Getting Unsatisfied dependency expressed exception on quartz + Spring scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-4

I'm trying to create beans at run time by using the @Configuration and the @Bean annotations in spring boot.The reason of using this approach is that i'll get a list of Tasks from Database and scheduler creates a job for every task. But for some reasons, i'm getting following exception when

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cronTriggerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/hello/QuartzConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.hello.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

**Code**

```
@Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.hello") 
    public class QuartzConfiguration {


        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Bean
        public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
            AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();

            jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            return jobFactory;
        }


        @Bean
        public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
            JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
            factory.setJobClass(SampleJob.class);
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("name", "RAM");
            map.put(MyJobTwo.COUNT, 1);
            factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
            factory.setGroup("mygroup");
            factory.setName("myjob");
            return factory;
        }
        @Bean
        public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(String triggerName, String myGroup){
            CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
            stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
            stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
            stFactory.setName(triggerName);
            stFactory.setGroup(myGroup);

            stFactory.setCronExpression("0/10 * * * * ?"); //0/10 * * * * ?
            return stFactory;
        }


        @Bean
        public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
            SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
            scheduler.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
            scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean("triggerName","MyGroup").getObject());
            return scheduler;
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you cannot do this:

```
        @Bean
        public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(String triggerName, String myGroup){
            CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
            stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
            stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
            stFactory.setName(triggerName);
            stFactory.setGroup(myGroup);

            stFactory.setCronExpression("0/10 * * * * ?"); //0/10 * * * * ?
            return stFactory;
        }
```

If you do this, spring will try to autowire `triggerName` and `myGroup` from application context, so you just remove the `@Bean` annotation, everything should be fine.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setName("triggerName");
        stFactory.setGroup("myGroup");

        stFactory.setCronExpression("0/10 * * * * ?"); //0/10 * * * * ?
        return stFactory;
    }

        @Bean
        public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
            SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
            scheduler.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
            scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
            return scheduler;
        }
```

Comment: if i do so then i get the following exception 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/hello/QuartzConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I already doing creating scheduler by doing this way. The problem comes, when i need set the triggerName, groupName and schulerTime thourgh parameters .